# How to convert a snapshot to a snapshot to an Image in Openstack?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

It seems that snapshots and instances are very similar (e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/527449/why-does-openstack-distinguish-images-from-snapshots).

However, I've been unable to share snapshots publicly globally (i.e. across all projects). Note, I'm a user of the OpenStack installation, not an administrator of the installation.

Assuming that Images don't suffer the same limitation of Snapshots, is there a procedure for convert a snapshot to an image? If not, maybe I should ask a separate question, but my cloud admin tells me it needs to be an image.

Answer (score 1):

for download

glance-image download

Comment: I didn't actually try this, but it is basically the same as what I did try, just using another tool that we've been using (the openstack python cli). Unfortunately, I don't think it would work for me, I kept getting errors with the analogous command because for some reason the snapshot was showing size 0 when I tried. I'll document in another answer.

Comment: are you using which backend,  did you booted instance with volume?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I tried this:

```
openstack image save --file NixOS.qcow2 5426bbcf-06b3-42f3-b117-37395e7dde83
```

However, the reported size of NixOS.qcow2 was always 0 bytes. Not good. Well, the issue was apparently related to the fact that is is also what was reported in OpenStack and Horizon for the size of the Snapshot. So something weird was going on, but functionally, I could still use the snapshot to create instances without issue.

I then created a volume of a snapshot in horizon (when shut off, couldn't create a volume when shelved), then used this command to create an image from the newly created volume (`NixSnapVol`):

```
openstack image create --volume NixSnapVol NixSnapVol-img
```

Interestingly the reported size went from 41GB to 45GB, maybe that was part of the issue. Anyway, seems to work now, and bonus is that it is now RAW type instead of qcow2, so I don't need to do the conversion (our system largely benefits from using RAW as we have a ceph backend).